# Send an mail via phonegap and jquerymobile form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a jquerymobile form and I want to send an standartized email for validation which is created of the form where the user fills its data in.

Is there an easy jquerymobile solution or do I have to use phonegap?

Do you have any ideas/tutorials/suggestions how to do that?

thx in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make an ajax post to a server that collects the informations from the form and sends an email
there are a million / gazzillian examples on the internet if your search, you have not really said what server language you will be doing the sending with.

Comment: thx for your reply! Is there possibly a solution to send it directly via the android/iphone phone? If not I would use google app engine as server, so is there probably a good tutorial for that?